# Get selectedValue dropdownList in controller at runtime

Tags: asp.net-mvc, runtime, html.dropdownlistfor, selectedvalue

I want to set the values of a dropdownList according to the selectedValue of another dropdownList.

So for example :

```
ViewBag.Brand = new SelectList(db.Brand, "Libel", "Libel");
ViewBag.IdModel = new SelectList(db.Model.Where(model => model.Brand == ViewBag.Brand.SelectedValue), "IdModel", "Descriptive");
```

I know this isn't working but it's to show the logic I would like to have.

And this is my view :

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.IdModel, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.DropDownList("IdModel", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.IdModel, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Brand, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.DropDownList("Brand", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.IdModel, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

Is their any simple way to do this?

Thank's !

Answer (score 1):

In your case your need to ajax call or server call when you change brand dropdown box.
See Below example it is just used static data to identify the when brand model is change then automatically changed model dropdown using jquery(Client Side).

**View Side:-**

```
@*Display the elements in the page*@
@*------------------------------------------------*@
<script type="text/javascript" 
      src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="col-md-10">  
     @Html.DropDownList("Brand", (SelectList)ViewBag.Brand, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class =
         "form-control" } })
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="col-md-10">
      @Html.DropDownList("IdModel", (SelectList)ViewBag.IdModel, new {htmlAttributes = new { 
        @class = "form-control" } })
  </div>
</div>
@*------------------------------------------------*@


@*Script for call the server side function when you changed brand combo from jquery*@
@*------------------------------------------------*@
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function () {
      $("#Brand").change(function () {
        var selectedItem = $(this).val();
         $.ajax({
             cache: false,
             type: "GET",
             url: "/Home/GetModelFromBrand", // User your action and controller name 
             data: { "Brandid": selectedItem },
             success: function (data) {
                 $("#IdModel").empty();
                    $.each(data, function (id, option) {
                        $("#IdModel").append($('<option>
                              </option>').val(option.IdModel).html(option.Descriptive));
                    });
                },
                error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                    alert('Failed to retrieve states.');
                }
            });
        });
     });
 </script> 
 @*------------------------------------------------*@
```

**Controller Side:-**

```
//Get Method to load the view
//==============================================================
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var brands = new SelectList(new[]
                              {
                                  new {Libel="Brand1",},
                                  new {Libel="Brand2",},  
                              },
                             "Libel", "Libel");

    //=======Suppose Brand1 have idmodels1 , idmodels2 models 
    var idmodels = new SelectList(new[]
                              {
                                  new {IdModel="1",Descriptive="idmodels1",},
                                  new {IdModel="2",Descriptive="idmodels2",},

                              },
                              "IdModel", "Descriptive");
    ViewBag.Brand = brands;
    ViewBag.IdModel = idmodels;
    return View();
}
//==============================================================


//Get Action when changed brand combo
//==============================================================
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
public ActionResult GetModelFromBrand(string Brandid)
{
   var obj = new[] {
                            new {IdModel = 3,
                                                 Descriptive = "idmodels3"},
                            new {IdModel = 4,
                                                 Descriptive = "idmodels4"},
                            new {IdModel = 5,
                                                 Descriptive = "idmodels5"}
                        };


    return Json(obj, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
//==============================================================
```

Answer (score 0):

there are 2 ways:

1 do it on client;
2 do it on server

1. On client. Second drop down options should contain ids with brand id, then you could write javascript which should change selected index of second drop down based on selected value of first drop down. Here need to base on your model structure.
2. On server. Do postbacks on each change of first drop down. And return each time new model for second drop down based on posted value from first drop down.